# How can I check if same text appears in two different files

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I want to check (trick or any shortcut) whether text-string exists in two files.

The content of file one is

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
d.txt
```

The content of file two is

```
c.txt
a.txt
d.txt
```

How I can check if string in file one has matching string in file two?

Comment: What is sourcey and destinationy about the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

command

Method1:

```
for i in `cat p1`; do grep -i "$i" p2 >/dev/null; if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then echo "$i exsists in both files"; else echo "$i doesnt exsists in file p2"; fi; done
```

output

```
a.txt exsists in both files
b.txt doesnt exsists in file p2
c.txt exsists in both files
d.txt exsists in both files
```

Answer (score 1):

With `join`, `sort` and `grep`

```
join <(sort /path/to/source) <(sort /path/to/destination) | grep '<string to check>
```

Tests

```
cat source
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
d.txt

cat destination
c.txt
a.txt
d.txt

join <(sort source) <(sort destination) | grep 'a.txt'
a.txt

join <(sort source) <(sort destination) | grep 'b.txt'
```

If the requirement is to check if the content of two files is non-matching one can issue the following command

```
cmp --silent <(sort source) <(sort destination) || echo "files are different"
```

Tests

```
cmp --silent <(sort source) <(sort destination) || echo "files are different"
files are different
```

To add all lines in source file not contained in destination file in /var/tmp/unmatched file

```
comm -23 <(sort source) <(sort destination) > /var/tmp/unmatched
```

To delete from source file all lines not contained in destination file

```
comm -1 <(sort source) <(sort destination) >| source
```

Since we are in bash and if you have set noclobber as `set -o noclobber`, then you should use the syntax `>|`.

Comment: but I dont know content of the files say - grep 'a.txt'. Rather I want to check Source string is present in Destination string and if not add it to /dev/null etc.

Comment: @Rocky86 I'm not following your requirement. Please [`edit`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/573633/edit) your question and add information about the output that you are expecting.

Comment: @Rocky86 You said _How I can check if string in source file has matching string in destination file?_  This implies that you have a string that you want to check.

Comment: @PauloTomé check now. What I am trying tio do is, compare if matching string available in both files then do some operation else dump that string in another file

Comment: Confirm if this is your requirement: To check if the text (all lines) in source files matches the text (all lines) in destination file.

Comment: yes. nonmatching should be dumped into another file

Comment: When the files are nonmatching what should be dumped into another file?

Comment: unmatched string e.g. b.txt is not in destination so it will be redirected to some another file /var/tmp/unmatched.

Comment: Confirm if this is your requirement: Modify source file in order that all lines not contained in destination file are deleted and added to  /var/tmp/unmatched file.

Comment: @PauloTomé Yes confirmed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105700/discussion-between-rocky86-and-paulo-tome).

Comment: @PauloTomé not covered proper scenario in suggested answer. to simplify again - I want to first ensure source_a.txt is present in destination_a.txt if it is then do "file is present" else "file is not present & dump to /var/tmp/unmatched"

Comment: @Rocky86 See my question in chat.

Comment: @Rocky86 Your comments here indicates that your question still does not contain all relevant information. It does not, for example, say anything about writing things to output files.

Answer (score 0):

Done by using below awk command

```
f2count=`awk 'END{print NR}' p2`
f1count=`awk 'END{print NR}' p1 `
comm_p1_p2=`awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}($0 in a){print $0}' p1 p2| awk 'END{print NR}'`

if [[ $f1count -eq $f2count ]] && [[ $f1count -eq $comm_p1_p2 ]]; then echo "both files p1  and p2 content are same"; else echo "different content found on file p1  and p2"; fi
```